# Python count and probability

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following data :

```
Name    Item
peter   apple
peter   apple
Ben     banana
peter   banana
```

I want to print

```
frequency of what peter eat :
apple 2 
banana 1
```

this is my code

```
u, count = np.unique(data['Item'], return_counts=True)

process = u[np.where(data['Name']= 'peter')[0]]

process2 = dict(Counter(process))
print "Item\frequency"

for k, v in process2.items():
print '{0:.0f}\t{1}'.format(k,v)
```

but it got error 
I also want to calculate the probability of peter eat apple next time 
but I dont have any idea , any suggestion ?

Comment: error : keyword can't be an expression

Comment: What is `data` ? Pandas DataFrame? Numpy record array? Which line are you getting the error

Comment: I used Pandas to read my data file

Comment: process = u[np.where(data['Name']= 'peter')[0]]

this have error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is as the other answer indicates, you cannot use `data['Name'] = 'peter'` as a function parameter, you actually intended to use - `np.where(data['Name'] == 'peter')` .

But, given that you are using `pandas` , and I am guessing `data` is a pandas `DataFrame` . In which case, what you really want can be achieved using `DataFrame.groupby`. Example -

```
data[data['Name']=='peter'].groupby('Item').count()
```

Demo -

```
In [7]: data[data['Name']=='peter'].groupby('Item').count()
Out[7]:
        Name
Item
apple      2
banana     1
```

---

If you want this printed in a loop, you can use -

```
df = data[data['Name']=='peter'].groupby('Item').count()
for fruit,count in df['Name'].iteritems():
    print('{0}\t{1}'.format(fruit,count))
```

Demo -

```
In [24]: df = data[data['Name']=='peter'].groupby('Item').count()

In [25]: for fruit,count in df['Name'].iteritems():
   ....:     print('{0}\t{1}'.format(fruit,count))
   ....:
apple   2
banana  1
```

---

For the updated issue that the OP was getting, where he was getting the following error -

> TypeError: invalid type comparison

The issue occurs in this case because in the real data for the OP , the column has numeric values (float/int) , but the OP was comparing the values against string, and hence getting the error. Example -

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   0  1
0  1  2

In [31]: df[0]=='asd'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-e7bacd79d320> in <module>()
----> 1 df[0]=='asd'

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    612
    613             # scalars
--> 614             res = na_op(values, other)
    615             if np.isscalar(res):
    616                 raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series'

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    566                 result = getattr(x, name)(y)
    567                 if result is NotImplemented:
--> 568                     raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
    569             except (AttributeError):
    570                 result = op(x, y)

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

If your column is numeric, you should compare against numeric values, not string.

Comment: Thanks for answering , but it have "invalid type comparison" error

Comment: What is giving? Your method? If so, why are you using that? You should make use of `pandas` methods and functions if you are using pandas. Like I gave above.

Comment: yes, so it is a pandas DataFrame, use the method I gave.

Comment: thanks , but "invalid type comparison" error on line "data[data['Name']=='peter'].groupby('Item').count()"

Comment: What does this give you - `print(data[data['Name']=='peter'])` ?

Comment: Im not sure is it related , but the real data is not "apple "and "peter", is some number id like "123456", is it the reason why got error ?

Comment: Could be, use the real data instead of `'peter'`.

Comment: I did change it before I apply the code , and the error come out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92341/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-aaaabbbb).

Comment: The invalid type comparison would make a good question/answer, it feels tacked on here. Would be more googleable as a separate question.

Comment: Yea, sure I will create a question and answer it.

Comment: Added a quesiton/answer for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142726/invalid-type-comparison-error-when-comparing-data

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby the name and use `value_counts`:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("Name")["Item"].value_counts()
Out[11]:
Name
Ben    banana    1
peter  apple     2
       banana    1
dtype: int64
```

Potentially you could unstack these into columns:

```
In [12]: df.groupby("Name")["Item"].value_counts().unstack(1)
Out[12]:
       apple  banana
Name
Ben      NaN       1
peter      2       1

In [13]: res = df.groupby("Name")["Item"].value_counts().unstack(1).fillna(0)

In [13]: res
Out[13]:
       apple  banana
Name
Ben        0       1
peter      2       1
```

To get the probabilities divide by the sum:

```
In [14]: res = res.div(res.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

In [15]: res
Out[15]:
          apple    banana
Name
Ben    0.000000  1.000000
peter  0.666667  0.333333
```

and the probability peter eats an apple next time:

```
In [16]: res.loc["peter", "apple"]
Out[16]: 0.66666666666666663
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Pandas or NumPy, but one problem I can see is that:

```
data['Name'] = 'peter'
```

is an assignment statement.

Whereas you probably want to check for equality:

```
data['Name'] == 'peter'
```

Also, unless your indentation was messed up in pasting your code here, you need to indent the body of your for statement, or you'll find another error once you cleared up this one.

```
for k, v in process2.items():
    print '{0:.0f}\t{1}'.format(k,v)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I changed and it got "invalid type comparison" error

Comment: What is the type of data["Name"]? Try `print typeof(data["Name"]).

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Answer (score 0):

If you're not dead set on using numpy:

```
import collections
import csv

data = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    infile.readline()  # fet rid of the header
    for name, food in csv.reader(infile):
        data[name][food] += 1

for name, d in data.iteritems():
    print("frequency of what" name, "ate:")
    total = float(sum(d.values()))
    for food, count in d.iteritems():
        print(food, count, "probability:", count/total)
```

Comment: thanks for answering , but I need to use numpy . thanks anyway :)